# Check inputs for bad characters, NaN, length

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am searching for a general input check and I already found some things like NaN or if it is to short but how can you **check if there are characters like ($§?=)** which you do not want in your input to be?

My second question is what is important to check if you wanna rename a file using an input. Except length.

**EDIT:**

```
if($ParID -lt 6) {
        $specific_error = "Par ID is is too short!"
    } else { #else 1
        if(!($ParID -match "[1-999999]")) {
            $specific_error = "Par ID must only contain numbers!"
        } else { #else 2

        }#else 2
    } #else 1
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
$ParIDInbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox #initialization -> initializes the input box

$ParIDInbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,30) #Location -> where the label is located in the window

$ParIDInbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) #Size -> defines the size of the inputbox

$ParIDInbox.MaxLength = 6 #sets max. length of the input box to 6
```

Comment: Can you share some code withus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check whether the filename contains any unwanted character you can use a `regex`:

```
$invalidCharacter = '$§?='
[regex]$invalidCharacter = '[{0}]' -f ([regex]::Escape($invalidCharacter))
if ($invalidCharacter.IsMatch($yourFileName))
{
    # filename contains some invalid character ...
}
```

To ensure the filename is valid, you could use the [GetInvalidFileNameChars](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars(v=vs.110).aspx) .NET method to retrieve all invalid character and again use a `regex` to check whether the filename is valid:

```
[regex]$containsInvalidCharacter = '[{0}]' -f ([regex]::Escape([System.IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars()))
$yourFileName = 'invali?idFilename.txt'

if ($containsInvalidCharacter.IsMatch($yourFileName))
{
    # filename is invalid...
}
```

Comment: This is really helpful but how do I check if there are ONLY number (0-9) and letters (a-z) ?

Comment: You can use a regex for that ;-)

Comment: okay thanks I think you answered my question very clearly thanks for that :D